# "Plugging in" Docker Container to Host Network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker to network together two containers and one of the containers needs to be able to access the host network for service discovery. I cannot use `-net=host` because that makes the other container inaccessible.

What I am looking for is essentially a way to add the `host` network as a "secondary" network to the docker container so it can access other containers, as well as the host network.

Hopefully that makes sense. Docker is still very new to me so I apologize if my explanation is lacking.

EDIT: To elaborate more on the kind of discovery I need, basically I am running Plex media server inside a container and PlexConnect inside another container. In order for PlexConnect to be able to detect the right IP for Plex, it needs to be able to access the 192.168 local network of the host since it serves as the DNS for an AppleTV outside the Docker network.

So containers are as follows:

- Plex (bridge mode and binds to the host port 192.168.1.100:32400)
- PlexConnect (separate subnet of bridge mode, needs to be able to access 192.168.1.100:32400)

tl;dr I need what BMitch suggested below but the `docker-compose` version.

Comment: Is the "service discovery" data routable or do you have to have an IP/interface on that host network? If IP, DHCP or static? Are you on a VM or physical host?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework. Take note of the [Take note about vms](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#things-to-note) . If your on something like EC2 where you can't change vnetwork settings it requires some MAC shuffling.

Comment: Regarding "one of the containers needs to be able to access the host network for service discovery" .. can you clarify this? What service discovery system are you using?  It could be that you can still run this with a single bridged interface, but exposing things through that in the right way.

Comment: Added more notes to the original post :)

Comment: FYI, I just retracted my answer because I realized it was the host network that was just passing through the command and showing the docker networks there too. But I have seen multiple bridged or overlay networks before, so should be possible.

Comment: Further info: I can also accept somehow proxying 192.168.1.100:32400 to a Docker network IP on the PlexConnect container if someone knows how to do that?